# Sorting children of a tree node in angular

Tags: angular, sorting, service, treeview, components

I have an angular tree view with nodes street, city,  state, country.

State is a child node of Country, City is a child node of State and so on.
Also each node has its own respective children.

> ex: Germany, France, Sweden, Norway is the values in the country node.
>   Clicking on Germany would show the states like Berlin, Bavaria,
>   Saarland, and further selecting Bavaria will show the cities in
>   Bavaria and later choosing the city will show its street.

However, I am not able to the sort these list of countries, states, cities, and streets.

The name is stored in a variable called `label`. I was using the following to sort an array. :

```
  getNames(id: string): Observable<Name[]> {

return this.httpClient
  .get(
    this.environmentService.endpoints.<<--insert url here-->
  )
  .pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      data.sort((a, b) => {
          return a.Name > b.Name ? 1 : -1

      })
      return data
    })
  ) as Observable<Name[]>
 }
```

I used a similar kind for tree

It reshuffles but does not sort alphabetically.

Is there a way to sort my object alphabetically?

P.S: I want to sort it in service and then send it to the component

Answer (score -1):

Can you show more code on how you are sorting? you shouldn't need to use a pipe map since arrays have their own native sort function.

```
sortFn(myArray: Array<any>, label: string) {
   return myArray.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[label] < b[label]) return -1;
    if (a[label] > b[label]) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: So your updated function, that is what you currently have and it is randomly moving your labels around? or do you have a different function that is returning a tree structure? also, what does the tree structure look like?

Comment: ya. this one works fine for other types but not tree

Comment: you might have to create a recursive call to sort a tree so that you can sort all layers... But I can't see why that wouldn't work for at least the top layer

Comment: should i use something like node.data.label instead of just label

Comment: I would have to see your tree structure